# Error message More than one column has the same display name

Tags: sql

I keep getting the error message

> More than one column has the same display name

but I cannot find the route cause. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT
    gl_ap_details.ledger_name,
    gl_ap_details.company_code,
    gl_ap_details.location_code, 
    gl_ap_details.cost_center, 
    gl_ap_details.account_number,
    gl_ap_details.account_name, 
    gl_ap_details.product_code,
    gl_ap_details.channel_code,
    gl_ap_details.journal_name,
    gl_ap_details.line_description,
    gl_ap_details.gl_posted_date,
    gl_ap_details.currency,
    gl_ap_details.je_source,
    gl_ap_details.je_category, 
    gl_ap_details.effective_date,
    gl_ap_details.created_by,
    gl_ap_details.invoice_num,
    gl_ap_details.invoice_id,
    gl_ap_details.invoice_date,
    gl_ap_details.vendor_name,
    gl_ap_details.vendor_number,
    gl_ap_details.invoice_image,
    gl_ap_details.po_number,
    gl_ap_details.po_requestor,
    gl_ap_details.period_name,
    gl_ap_details.amount,
    gl_ap_details.gl_posted_date,
    gl_ap_details.project_code
FROM
    wbr_global.gl_ap_details
WHERE
    wbr_global.gl_ap_details.ledger_name = 'Amazon.com, Inc.'
    AND cost_center IN ('1172')
    AND period_name = 'JUL-21'
    AND wbr_global.gl_ap_details.account_number = '60820'
GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28;
```

Comment: Search for gl_posted_date. It's selected more than once without a derived column name.

Comment: ALso: since your column list in the `SELECT` doesn't contain any aggregations (like `COUNT`,  `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`) - the whole `GROUP BY` is totally useless ....

Comment: @marc_s: it's essentially the same as `select distinct ....` (just a bit longer and more error prone)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. If you post that as the answer I can mark it as answered.